# No object was specified to query

Tags: python, maya

My first question here, because i am really stuck with this problem:

I need to query the height of some polycones:

```
for lash in self.lashes:
   old_length = cmds.polyCone((self.lashesGroup+"|"+lash[0]), q=True, h=True)
```

`(self.lashesGroup + "|" + lash[0])` does exist. It is a string, looking like this: `"lashesGroup|lash0"` (the second ends with 1 the third with 2 etc.). Everything seems to be fine but an error occurs saying:

> No object was specified to query.

Is there a special treatment for objects in groups?

Comment: Are you sure the object exists in the scene? Check it with `cmds.objExists( string )` command

Comment: i just checked, and it returns true. it is so strange. if i am creating new objects and parent them to the group i can query them, but there seems to be a problem with the objects i administrate in that lashes-list

Comment: for lash in self.lashes:
            cmds.polyColorPerVertex(self.lashesGroup+"|"+lash[0], colorRGB=color, colorDisplayOption=True) <---- this works btw.. it is almost the same code..

Comment: sry - again: i guess it  might be a reaction to this warning: # Warning: Cannot parent components or objects in the underworld. i get it for a bend deformer i am adding to the lashesGroup. i read a little bit about the underworld but couldnt figure out, how to add the deformer anyway without getting the warning. it has to be in that group - any suggestions?

Comment: If it is a useless warning, i go for try/except pass

Comment: thanks for the advices - i discovered that the warning is not the problem, because it is not working neither if i do not add the deformer and do not get

Comment: edit : * the warning